# Foreign Key SQL: How can I reference two attributes in one table to a composite primary key that contains 3 columns in the other table?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE SECTION,`
SectionNo int,
Semester CHAR(7),
CourseID CHAR(8),
PRIMARY KEY (SectionNo, Semester, CourseID),
FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) REFERENCES COURSE (CourseID),

);

CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION(
StudentID int,
SectionNo int,
Semester char(7),
PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, SectionNo, Semester),
FOREIGN KEY (SectionNo, Semester) REFERENCES Section (SectionNo, Semester),
```

> *Underline is coming up under "Section". The error says, "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Section' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key." How do I fix this?!*

```
FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Student (StudentID),

);
```

Comment: Well, the error message is correct. You cannot uniquely identify a row in `Section` using just `SectionNo` and `Semester`, given that it's declared primary key also includes `CourseID`. We might be able to help more if you'd offered us any actual explanation of what you're trying to model.

Comment: I have been given entities, attributes and datatypes to create six different tables. The SECTION table has 3 Primary Keys therefore I can't add just SectionNo and Semester into one bracket in the SECTION table. Any suggestions?

Comment: If by "The registration", you mean "the `Section` table, then no, it doesn't have 3 primary keys (indeed, in SQL, you're limited to at most one PK per table, hence the word primary in its name). It has a *single* primary key that contains 3 columns. That means in order to reference that primary key, you need 3 columns containing the same sorts of data as in the original.

Comment: Imagine that your `Section` table contains two rows (columns in same order as shown in your question):- row 1 contains `1,abc,def` and row 2 contains `1,abc,ghi`. That is, they're for two different courses but have the same `SectionNo` and `Semester` values. Now we insert a row into `Registration`: `2,1,abc` - what does that registration *mean*?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So how do I go about referencing SectionNo and Semester to the REGISTRATION table since there are three columns in the Primary Key?

Answer (score 0):

**Probably**

Judging (uh... guessing) from your chosen names, a student ought to register in a certain semester in a certain section *of a certain course*. So your registration table is probably missing a course column.

There would be a 3-column FK to the 3-column PK. Also the registration PK would be all 4 columns.

**But if**

If you were recording just a semester and course, that would be an inclusion dependency (IND) from REGISTRATION to COURSE. A foreign key (FK) is an IND to a key. (Well, in SQL it's an IND to a superkey, SQL KEY/UNIQUE.) An IND from columns to others means every source subrow value ahs to appear as a target subrow value. Ie the projection of the source on its IND columns MINUS the projection of the target on its IND columns has to be empty.

That IND means every REGISTRATION semester-course subrow value has to appear as a COURSE subrow value. Which means

```
NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT Semester,Course FROM REGISTRATION
    EXCEPT SELECT Semester,Course FROM COURSE
)
```

If you have no EXCEPT/MINUS then there's an idiom with LEFT JOIN.

**You wish**

You can't easily express this constraint in most SQL DBMSs. (Although the standard describes the functionality.) You usually have to use triggers on updates to check all but a small number of non-trivial constraints in SQL.